# The collection of jobs that have not been done on time

Tags: single-word-requests

Looking for word for an amount of work that had to be done, but was not and now aggregated into a collection of undone work.

> She was falling behind the rest of the class, having 7 unfinished assignments in her **______**

Comment: Methinks thou art undone.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You are probably looking for ***[backlog](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/backlog):***

> a large number of things that you should have done before and must do now:
>
> - *I've got a huge backlog of work to do.*

(Cambridge Dictionary)

Comment: Super! Merci! Will accept the answer in 11 minutes (can't do it now for some reason).

Comment: @Eduard I think that the reason is to give other users at least _some_ time to compose their own answers before you check off the first answer and move on.

Comment: @Arthur - true, anyway OP can remove and change the green tick anytime if better answers are posted.

Answer (score 12):

I think backlog is best, but allow me to offer an alternative, in-basket (or in-box).

This refers to a stereotypical office worker having two wire baskets at different corners of the desk, one marked **IN** and the other marked **OUT**.  The in-basket contained files or messages that had not been taken care of, that were pending work by the employee.  The out-basket contained those items that had been completed and just needed to be filed or delivered.

Consider this poor cartoon person's dilemma:

[image]

Comment: Although, I am 100% satisfied with backlog, but your reasoning is so great, that I can't not up vote it.

Comment: Inbox was the first word that popped into my head when reading the question, but backlog does seem to be a better fit. Upvotes all round!